# Left join of nested arrays, objects and properties into a single flat table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Overview**

I use [Microsoft OData Query Builder library](https://www.odata.org/blog/odataquerybuilder-a-cross-browser-javascript-library-for-building-odata-queries-3/) to generate nested tables but I need flat table. To achieve this I have 2 possible solutions,

1. Modify the nested JSON I receive to create a flat table
2. Let OData Query Builder generate nested tables and then I convert them into flat table.

I tried first approach and stuck with it - https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/10/
I am expecting output to be like this,

```
ID  Name    Products.0.ID
999 Meat    17987   
999 Meat    17988
999 Meat    17989
999 Meat    17990
```

**Problem with 2nd approach**

***For example (What I have)***, If I have a table like this,

[image]

***What I want --- only for first tr from picture, rest will follow same logic***

```
MainTable.Name  Product.ID Product.Name Product.Description ProductDetail.Details
Food                0         Bread        Whole gain bread      
Food                1         Milk         Low Fat Milk      Details of product 1
```

My scenario is far more dynamic and complex then above, but I am not sure where to start.

**Why I think it's not duplicate**

I don't need flatten array, I wasn't able to find the correct word before which is "Cartesian product". I can use underscore.js to flatten arrays but that's not what I want, I want to combine elements of parent arrays with child arrays.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do "solution 2", and if so would it be possible to get the raw html of what you have now table wise?  I can't really tell from the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your snippet. Sorry for the messy code. Hope it helps. [(js fidle here)](https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/29/)

```
  /**
   * @param {array} array - The data to be converted into flat view
   * @param {array} schema - Accumulates names and represents names of the columns
   * @param {array} record - Array with values accumulated so far with indexes corresponding to schema
   * @param {array} path - Accumulates current path (names of all properties to go through to get to the object)
   * @return {array} - Array of flat records with content of all nested objects
   */
  function processMany(array, schema, record = [], path = []) {
    var records = [];
    if (array.length == 0) {
      // there is no objects in current array, just return the record
      records.push(record);
    } else {
      array.forEach(function(obj) {
        var recordClone = record.slice(0);
        var r = processSingle(obj, schema, recordClone, path);
        // there are objects in current array, accumulate whatever is parsed from each object and return it
        records = records.concat(r);
      });
    }
    return records;
  }

  /**
   * @param {hash} object - The data to be converted into flat view
   * @param {array} schema - Accumulates names and represents names of the columns
   * @param {array} record - Array with values accumulated so far with indexes corresponding to schema
   * @param {array} path - Accumulates current path (names of all properties to go through to get to the object)
   * @return {array} - Array of flat records with content of all nested objects
   */
  function processSingle(object, schema, record, path) {
    var nestedObjects = [],
      nestedArrays = [];
    var records = [];
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
      var value = object[key];
      // we need to treat differently arrays, objects and plain values
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        // it is array, save it for later
        nestedArrays.push({
          key: key,
          value: value
        });
      } else if (value && value.constructor == Object) {
        // it is object (hash), save it for later
        nestedObjects.push({
          key: key,
          value: value
        });
      } else {
        // it is plain value, just add it to record 
        var keyPath = path.concat(key);
        record = processSimpleValue(value, schema, record, keyPath);
      }
    });
    if (nestedObjects.length == 0) {
        // if there are no nested objects we have only one record so far
      records = [record];
    } else {
        // if there are nested objects, each of them has one or more records in it 
      // if a nested object contains more than one record each next nested object 
      // will fill each of the records returned by the previous nested object
        records = [record];
      nestedObjects.forEach(function(keyValue) {
        var thisObjectRecords = [];
        records.forEach(function(record) {
          var keyPath = path.concat(keyValue.key);
          var recordClone = record.slice(0);
          var object = keyValue.value;
          var r = processSingle(object, schema, recordClone, keyPath)
          thisObjectRecords = thisObjectRecords.concat(r); 
        });
        records = thisObjectRecords; // one or more records here
      });
    }
    if (nestedArrays.length == 0) {
        // we have no nested arrays; it means we return everything we have processed so far
      return records;
    } else {
        // each of the nested arrays will return one or more records, we need to accumulate it and return
      var nestedRecords = [];
      nestedArrays.forEach(function(keyValue) {
        // we need to fill each of the records we have with information from nested arrays
        records.forEach(function(record) {
          var keyPath = path.concat(keyValue.key);
          var recordClone = record.slice(0);
          var array = keyValue.value;
          var r = processMany(array, schema, recordClone, keyPath)
          nestedRecords = nestedRecords.concat(r); // one or more records here
        });
      });
      return nestedRecords;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param {string|number|null} value - The data to be added to the record
   * @param {array} schema - Accumulates names and represents names of the columns
   * @param {array} record - Array with values accumulated so far with indexes corresponding to schema
   * @param {array} path - Accumulates current path (names of all properties to go through to get to the object)
   */
  function processSimpleValue(value, schema, record, path) {
    var index = addToSchema(schema, path);
    record[index] = value;
    return record;
  }

  function pathToS(path) {
    return path.join('.');
  }

  /**
   * Returns index of of the path in schema, adds the path to the schema if it is not present in it
   * @return {number} index of current path in schema
   */
  function addToSchema(schema, path) {
    var pathS = pathToS(path);
    var i = schema.indexOf(pathS);
    if (i < 0) {
      i = schema.length;
      schema.push(pathS);
    }
    return i;
  }

  var flatHeaders = [];
  var flatData = processMany(data, flatHeaders);
```

Comment: thank you so much +1, I looked at your fiddle, it works very nice, but there is a problem, when product array is empty it should add empty cells to it instead, please see here it ignores milk category when there are no products, I want to add 1 row only then and rest columns empty, https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/17/ here is the logic to do so - https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/18/, thanks

Comment: thanks, I am not export in JS that's why I am finding it difficult to amend, but I am learning, does your code works with any level of nested data ? as I have a dynamic + complex dataset, here it's not adding 3rd level - https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/20/

Comment: I think I am getting closer - https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/23/, but still not perfect

Comment: Didn't know you have nested arrays AND nested objects.
Well, this should work:
https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/26/

Comment: Hi Lev, I found a problem, it is showing me 2 rows when there should only be 1 row, please have look - https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/27/

Comment: it works fine here in your earlier examples - https://jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/6/, I am trying to understand code myself, but if you get chance to look at before me, would be great, thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114005/discussion-between-lev-denisov-and-mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not flattening. You can achieve what you want with function given below. It also works if there are multiple sub tables. For example if you have one sub table with 3 elements and one with 4, you will have `3*4=12` rows in total.

```js
var data = [{
  "Products": [{
    "ID": 17987
  }, {
    "ID": 17988
  }, {
    "ID": 17989
  }, {
    "ID": 17990
  }],
  "ID": "999",
  "Name": "Meat"
}];

var oneToMany = function(data) {


  var props = Object.keys(data).filter(function(x) {
    return data.hasOwnProperty(x);
  });

  var nonArrayProps = props.filter(function(x) {
    return !Array.isArray(data[x]);
  });

  var arrayProps = props.filter(function(x) {
    return Array.isArray(data[x]);
  });


  var baseObject = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < nonArrayProps.length; i++) {
    baseObject[nonArrayProps[i]] = data[nonArrayProps[i]];
  }

  var objects = [baseObject];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayProps.length; i++) {
    var prop = arrayProps[i];
    var array = data[prop];
    var newObjects = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length || j == 0; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < objects.length || k == 0; k++) {
        var newObj = clone(objects[k]);
        newObj[prop] = array[j];
        newObjects.push(newObj);
      }
    }
    objects = newObjects;
  }
  return objects;
}

function clone(obj) {
  var clone = {};
  for (property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) clone[property] = obj[property];
  }
  return clone;
}

function normalizeTable(tableData) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], tableData.map(oneToMany));
}

console.log(normalizeTable(data));
```

Comment: thank you so much +1, I looked at your fiddle, it works very nice, but there is a problem, when product array is empty it should add empty cells to it instead, please see here it ignores milk category when there are no products, I want to add 1 row only then and rest columns empty, jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/17 here is the logic to do so - jsfiddle.net/e14oL103/18, thanks

Comment: @Mathematics If you do it like that, it becomes a left join. If you are sure that is what you want you can also do that. Edited the solution to do left join instead of inner join.